# YOLO: How to change the frequency of mAP calculation in darknet code

Tags: yolo, darknet

I am training YOLOv2 with -map option to print mean Average Precision. I need to change the frequency at which the map is calculated. At this time it is calculated every 300 iterations which is too frequent for me. I want this to be computed every (say 2000 iterations). Is there a way to change the switch ot code?

I do see the following code in detector.c file which needs to be changed. Any input?

```
int calc_map_for_each = 4 * train_images_num / (net.batch * net.subdivisions);  // calculate mAP for each 4 Epochs
calc_map_for_each = fmax(calc_map_for_each, 100);
int next_map_calc = iter_map + calc_map_for_each;
next_map_calc = fmax(next_map_calc, net.burn_in);
next_map_calc = fmax(next_map_calc, 1000);
if (calc_map) {
    printf("\n (next mAP calculation at %d iterations) ", next_map_calc);
    if (mean_average_precision > 0) printf("\n Last accuracy mAP@0.5 = %2.2f %% ", mean_average_precision * 100);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are using Alexey's repo because of the `-map` option. In detector.c (https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/8c970498a296ed129ffef7d872ccc25d42d1afda/src/detector.c#L223) you may change the following code :

```
calc_map_for_each = fmax(calc_map_for_each, 100);
```

to

```
calc_map_for_each = fmax(calc_map_for_each, 1000);
```